# Data set for Recency Frequency Monetary (RFM) analysis

Tags: data-request, business, classification

I am looking for datasets for RFM analysis - The goal of the analysis is to use the RFM variables to predict whether a customer will respond favorably (0/1) on a future campaign.

I am looking for a dataset that contains a response variable for a previous campaign. I have already looked at the Online retail and Online retail II datasets - I am looking for something similar, but with a response variable.

Additionally, I am okay with artificially creating a response column on the Online retail dataset as well, as long as it is not randomly generated, but statistically related to the customer's attributes in some way that would closely resemble the customer's actual behavior.